# Not able to find Windows Store under my Visual C# in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have visual studio community 2017 and I am developing Universal Windows App for my school project. As per book, I needed one template named "Search Result Page" which as per book is located inside Windows Store but Windows Store and the Search Result Page is not populating in my visual studio. Help will be highly appreciated

[image: Screenshot of my VS]

Comment: did you search it in the Online Templates? [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185306(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Did you install the UWP Workload? Doesnt seem that way. Start the Visual Studio Installer and click Modify and select the very first "Workload".

Comment: I searched in Online Templates and still could not find it. I have already installed UWP workload during my VS Installation